# Customize the iOS VKB toolbar

Tags: codenameone

The native iOS VKB can have a toolbar, and this toolbar can have a blue "Done" text.

I would like to be able to translate the "Done" text into the local language of the app (the language bundle used by Codename One does not translate this text), also I would like to change the color of the "Done" text from blue to orange.

I don't know how to do these customizations with Codename One. Thank you for the directions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The word "done" is used when localizing. Notice the lower case `d`. So adding "done" = "Localized String" to the resource bundle should work.

Comment: Thank you, your suggestion worked: "done" is used by VKB, while "Done" is used by lightweight pickers, so I need both. What about color customization? Could you also answer this part of my question?

Comment: About the color customization, I found a solution in the developer guide: `Display.getInstance().setProperty("ios.doneButtonColor", String.valueOf(0xff4500));`